# WPF C# - "Unable to find namespace" error in MainWindows.g.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces, code-generation

I have created a Windows Desktop WPF application using C#. It was working for a few days, but today it just stopped working. The app's namespace is Keklist2BetaWinDesktopCSharp, but when I tried to run the program I got the error shown in the included screenshot.

I have tried restarting VS2015, and I have also located the file and tried to delete the extra "using" statements I found, but VS always regenerates the file and removes all of my fixes.

Why is Visual Studio looking for namespaces that never existed?

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Do a search all in your solution for that namespace.  You might have a type still using the same old namespace.  I bet it's in XAML and that' s why you're not seeing the error immediately.  Visual Studio won't always rename XAML when perform a name change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you changed project name after and VS is stuck with old name. You need to clear your solution and rebuild it. If that does not work search for old name in your project and then clear and rebuilt it. That should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! I hadn't changed the namespace at any point though, but it worked anyway.